# Bash file in google clasp displays "Unknown key: ___" when using the clasp setting command?

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

So I am trying to use clasp so I can update script editors on employees' time-sheets, but there are multiple of them so I want them all to update from one set of code. I wrote a Bash Script that is supposed to utilize the 'clasp setting' command to update the .clasp.json file so multiple files are updated.

```
clasp setting scriptID 1oem46C_4AxUpOPzvl7xwEWFX9sHe1WJ7Qvtxm-q2ERlMPTo-LFBaT7g9
clasp push
clasp setting scriptID 1ag4HJ1CFaWNMNeNccQUtV34aBTeOLZdbxZyfkOQaEABM1b4uexzq-b7p
clasp push
clasp setting scriptID 17prHiTYCT9Fx2tCD10DmnxRUGF9vw5WWH_2Vt0Hc_vE1Q2Y6CvhAxaN2 
clasp push
```

When it runs it goes through each command but displays 'Unknown key "scriptID"'. I believe the problem is it does not reset/update the .clasp.json file so it continually pushes to the orignal scriptID. I've looked at the clasp github but I am still confused about why it fails to recognize the key.

Answer (score 3):

#### The key is `scriptId` not `scriptID`

In the project root directory, try

```sh
cat .clasp.json
```

and you will see the key is (case-sensitive) "scriptId" not "scriptID".